# fadeIn doesn't work when used with JQuery Mobile in a Mobile App

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, fadein

I have multiple `<div>` in my view and i want to display the content of the first div when the page first loads. I am trying to use `fadeIn`, but even after using :first selector , the view displays all the content in the divs.

```
$(".section:first").fadeIn();
```

This works in normal desktop app, but not in my mobile view.

My Html code:

```
<form action="~/Home/About" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="formId" onkeyup="formkeyup();">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <div class="section">
        <h3>Step 1: Password</h3>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.Password" onkeyup=" return Validate() "/>
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                <input type="password" name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.ConfirmPwd" onkeyup=" return Validate() "/>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="divSection2" class="section">
        <h3>Step 2: Age</h3>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
<input type="button" id="SubmitId" name="SubmitId" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the inside the parenthesis in your .fadeIn() function

```
$(".section:first").fadeIn("slow")
```

also may we see your full jquery code?